# Displaying an image in a foreach

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, image, foreach

So I have login with LinkedIn and I'm trying to add a Facebook one.

I already have the "Signin with LinkedIn" button working, and am trying to add the Facebook one:

```
<div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                    @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                    {
                        var source = "~/Img/" + p.AuthenticationType + ".png";
                        <input type="image" src="@source" border="0" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%">
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
```

If I don't build the path like this, and give it src="~/Img/Facebook.png" or src="~/Img/LinkedIn.png" they work. How can I write the path so the pictures don't appear as broken elements on the page?

Comment: Well what does the URL look like in the served page when it's broken vs when it's working? My guess is that you'll need to resolve `~` yourself when you're building the URL manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Img/{0}", source))"
```

Comment: Presumably you could use string interpolation here? `src = "@Url.Content($"~/Img/{source})"`?

Comment: This worked, no need for the second @, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **c# 6.0** than you can use [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn961160.aspx) it'll give you same thing but in much cleaner way

```
src="@Url.Content($"~/Img/{@source}")"
```